# How AWS Application Load Balancer round robin distributes sequential traffic

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-application-load-balancer, round-robin

We are running our spring boot on AWS ECS with 2 instances on production. We have put an Application Load Balancer on top of it with round-robin algorithm for 2 targets but I am seeing that most the requests are going to only one instance. **Requests are sequential and stickiness is off.**

There are two requests coming from the same client in one it is just to pre-warm the local ehcache and second is the actual request which will create a deal. Now as per my knowledge in round-robin it cannot be possible as request 1 will go to Instance A while request 2 will go to Instance B -- but it is happening.

Please let me know where my understanding is wrong.